# Smooth CSS transform animations

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm looking at optimising CSS animations for performance.

From what I can find out using

```
.item { transform: translate(-25px,-50px)
```

is much more efficient than

```
.item { left: -25px; top: -50px }
```

I've setup a little animation that move and rotates a box `.balloon` which as multiple steps to the animation. The problem is though the animation becomes very jerky, even with positioning ans rotation declared for each step

Here is my standard CSS

```
@keyframes balloon {
    0%,100% { left:809px; top:50px; transform: rotate(0deg) }
    10% { transform: rotate(-9deg) }
    25%,75% { top:25px }
    50% { left:235px;top:75px }
    45% { transform: rotate(3deg) }
    75% { transform: rotate(12deg) }
}
```

This is my optimised CSS, which is where the jerky animation comes in to effect

```
@keyframes balloon {
    0% { transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0deg) }
    10% { transform: translate(-57.5px,-10px) rotate(-9deg) }
    25% { transform: translate(-143.75px,-25px) rotate(-4deg) }
    45% { transform: translate(-517.5px,22.5px) rotate(3deg) }
    50% { transform: translate(-575px,25px) rotate(4.5deg) }
    75% { transform: translate(-287.5px,-25px) rotate(12deg) }
    100% { transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0deg) }
}
```

Is there an alternative solution for this?

I've put a CodePen together [here](http://cdpn.io/beFKk).

Comment: If you don't like the way the easing function is then you have to change it. This has nothing to do with performance

Comment: Also, you cannot move an element part of a pixel, it will be rounded (thus there is no purpose for having it in your CSS)

Answer (score 1):

In your animation-property, try to add a value for the [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function)

Something like

```
animation: balloon 15s infinite linear;
```

would make it more smooth.

Comment: I did try linear after seeing that ease actually eased between each step rather that creating a smooth and flowing animation loop. Linear seems a little harsh, with my original animation CSS and the and the animation set to ease, it looked alot more natural